How to export site-search shortcuts?
I have dozens of shortcuts for site search on one MacBook (under Settings, Search engine, Site search). How do I export and import these to move them to another Mac? I know how to export/import bookmarks. Searching Brave settings for “export” yields no results.

Easiest? Copy whole profile, if you don't mind transferring passwords, forms, etc. /Users/[You]/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/
